# Crud Operation with SharePoint Multiline Rich Text

Tags: sharepoint-online, rich-text, multiline-text-field

I have a custom Page for adding data to List Item. For one Multiline Rich Text I want to perform CRUD Operation using Client Side Code (Rest API). I want to allow insert hyperlink, Picture from Html Page and save into SharePoint Rich Text Multiline column.

Any suggestions are Welcome.
Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: I'm currently working on something like this where we are making our own interface to a discussion list. I'm using the Pell rte (because it is so small and simple), and the file api to upload images to the image library and insert a link into the text field.

What issue are you facing?

Comment: I want to insert hyperlink , images to SharePoint Multiline rich text column from custom page for adding list item. I am not able to find any solution which allow to insert links, images to html text area and then insert it into SharePoint Multiline column using rest/jsom.